# User specific publish (subscriptions)

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

Here's a small issue I faced and couldn't find much info in the documentation. I am trying to create private chat messages. We have the following code to subscribe a user to a topic:

```js
export const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    somethingChanged: {
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('chat_messages'),
    },
  },
}
```

and to publish

```js
pubsub.publish('chat_messages', { somethingChanged: { sender_id: 1, receiver_id: 2, message: 'test' }});
```

I have used onConnect to verify that the user is authenticated

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    subscriptions: {
        onConnect: (connectionParams, webSocket) => {
            ...
            if (!authenticated) throw error
            ...
        },
    },
   ...
})
```

This works well when I want to subscribe users to a particular topic for example. But how do I implement, private user to user communication? I have tried the `withFilter` but can't seem to implement user specific authorization(with respect to a message) checks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-server-express-starter/tree/master/src/subscription/demo-1

With these features:

1. `jwt` based auth for websocket connection
2. User channel which means who can receive message, who can not.

There are some conceptions you need know:

1. there are two types user: **requestUser** and **subscribeUsers(include requestUser)**
2. you should write the code in `filterFn`, for who can receive the message which `requestUser` send.

For example:

There are three **subscribe users**: s1(client-1), s2(client-2), s3(client-3)

When a **request user(client-4)** send a message(maybe mutation), you can get **subscribe users** and **request users** through `context` argument of `filterFn`.

According to these two type `users'` informations. You can write your own bussiness logic in `filterFn` to decide who can receive message, who can't.

P.S. beside `context`, you can get `variables` argument in `filterFn` from client. That will give more information to decide who can receive message and who can't

Sorry for my English!

Comment: true but I had some trouble authenticating users for a channel. if inside the channel only specific user can receive updates (for example private chat). I posted something on github could you please have a look? https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1553